# How to get Year and Month of a DATE using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can I get the year and month of a date in the where clause using Oracle.

I used to be working with SQL server and it was as simple as YEAR(FIELDNAME) and MONTH(FIELDNAME).

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myschema.mytablename
WHERE   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  myDATE)  = 2017
```

however it gives ORA-30076 Error

Comment: Its connected to Oracle 11g

Comment: What's the data type of `myDATE`?

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried EXTRACT()?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2017-12-01') FROM DUAL;
2017

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2017-12-01') FROM DUAL;
12
```

I tried this in sql fiddle with 11g and it works in WHERE clause too.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb2b09/2

[image]

Comment: I need this to be in my where clause. Is it possible?

Comment: can you try SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_field_name = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE date_field_name); Basically extract function will extract the requested date attribute from given field name.

Comment: @user2597012 please **edit your question** to include the code you're running which throws this error.

Comment: Is the data type of field name used in extract function Date? If not then use DATE ahead of field_name.

Comment: The type is date, and as for the code the query I used is already here in my question...

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myschema.mytablename
WHERE   TO_CHAR(myDATE, 'YYYY') = '2017';
```

Explicitly convert year part of DATE into CHAR and compare it with literal.
For year and month comparison:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myschema.mytablename
    WHERE   TO_CHAR(myDATE, 'YYYY') = '2017' AND TO_CHAR(myDate, 'MM') = '07';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work, but a better alternative would be

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE MY_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                    AND TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the function EXTRACT() and it works good for me.

I'm gonna share the query code here:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR from s.CREATE_DATE) as YEAR, extract(MONTH from s.CREATE_DATE) as MONTH, s.SALES_PERSON_GID, COUNT(s.SALES_ORDER_ID) as "TOTAL ORDERS" FROM SALES_ORDERS s, SALES_ORDER_STATUS ss WHERE s.SALES_ORDER_ID = ss.SALES_ORDER_ID and ss.STATUS_TYPE_ID = 'SALE ORDER STATUS' and ss.STATUS_VALUE_GID = 'SALE ORDER STATUS_DELIVERED' GROUP BY  s.SALES_PERSON_GID,s.CREATE_DATE
```

[image]